# List product in Magento 2 home page

Tags: magento2

I have one foreach loop and I need to add custom html to every fourth row and it is completed.
Now I need to add dynamic array data into every fourth row like first 4th it will come first array value and 8th row it will come 2 array value.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: your issue solved or should I add answer for you?

Comment: Not solved you can add your comment

Answer (score 3):

```
var i=1;
foreach(condition) {
  if(i/4 == 0)
    //do your logic
   i++;
}
```

Its may help you

Answer (score 1):

Follow this below code :

```
<?php

$count = 1;
foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    if ($count % 4 == 0) {
        echo $value;
        // add your code
    }
    $count++;
}
?>
```